# Is there any tiles kind of concept in django

Tags: django, templates, generics, filter

I am looking for the following feature in django

I am writing a website, it contains many pages ex: home(displays all the books), details(selected book details), search(display the books based on search).

now the home page contains blocks like featured books, just-in books, most famous books.
details pages display  selected book details and it should display featured books, most famous books.

Now my Question is featured and famous books blocks are getting repeated, so is there any way to keep the template code separately(html) and also respective view method separately. so if I call these mini templates from main templates with arguments.

So that I can keep more generalized way and without repeating the code also in future if I want to change something I can do it at one place.

I am thinking to do it with filter but is that a good way? or django provided any mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can isolate reusable blocks of HTML into templates, and then include them in other templates with the [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) tag.

They don't take arguments, but you can either set up the main template so that the variables are set correctly, or use a [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with) tag to set the context before the `{% include %}`

As a concrete example, your view code could set up lists of books like this:

```
def book_detail_view(request, book_id):
    # Get the main book to display
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    # Get some other books
    featured_books = Book.objects.filter(featured=True).exclude(id=book_id)
    just_in_books = Book.objects.filter(release_data__gte=last_week, featured=False).exclude(id=book_id)

    return render("book_template.html",
                  dict(book=book,
                       featured_books=featured_books,
                       just_in_books=just_in_books))
```

Then, in your template (book_template.html):

```
<h1>Here's your book</h1>
<!-- fragment uses a context variable called "book" -->
{% include "book_fragment.html" %}

<h2>Here are some other featured books:</h2>
{% for featured_book in featured_books %}
    <!--Temporarily define book to be the featured book in the loop -->
    {% with featured_book as book %}
        {% include "book_fragment.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}

<h2>Here are some other books we just received:</h2>
<!-- This is a different way to do it, but might overwrite
     the original book variable -->
{% for book in just_in_books %}
    {% include "book_fragment.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if we are using include and with tags, in both cases we have to pass the objects to mini templates from the main template's view function. so again it got tightly coupled right? 

is there any other way that I can call mini-template from main template with arguments so that internally it will go to that particular view function and returns the response?

but your solution also acceptable because right now I am doing such a way only.

Comment: You should always set up the objects themselves in the view function, but you can use them in different ways in the template. And the view doesn't necessarily even have to know about the mini templates at all.

Comment: A couple other ideas occur to me.  1) Setup a 'Featured Books' mixin, for your main view, or 2) use javascript to load the featured book subtemplate and it's view function in a separate request.  It's not poosible (to my knowledge) to use two view functions to process on request

Answer (score 1):

This is what [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) are for. Once you have written the appropriate inclusion tags you can simply do `{% load books %} ... {% newbooks %} .. {% featuredbooks %} ... etc.` to put the divs containing the relevant information wherever you need.

Comment: so you mean to say write some custom tags?

Comment: Correct. That way you don't need to worry about misspelling a subtemplate name when things change since Django requires template tags to exist (and it's shorter to boot). Plus, you can pass context from the template to the tags, which is not possible when using `{% include %}`.

Comment: so you mean to say write some custom tags?
if it is Yes then how do we get mini templates response in main template.

if we call {% load books %} it will return some book objects right?
or do we write the books function to return the html content?

Please don't feel bad as I am asking more Questions, just to get clear idea. even it will help many people who all are struggling like me.

If possible please provide example like the way "Ian Clelland" provided.

Comment: Template tags can be seen as "miniviews", except instead of taking the request and the arguments from the URL, they take the template context (if explicitly asked for) and the arguments from the tag call. `{% load books %}` loads the template tag library called "books", and you must invoke the tags within the library separately. There are numerous examples on the page linked to, but pay special attention to the examples in the ["Inclusion tags"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) section, since most of yours will be of this type.

Comment: wow... grt... you made my day. Inclusion tags only I am looking for :)